# libical-based CalDAV server

Tags: c, icalendar, caldav, libical

I'm looking for some pointers or example code on how to build a CalDAV server using [libical](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeassociation/).  Specifically, how would you use libical to produce a text representation of an event that you could use to serve a response to a CalDAV request?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the source of [kcaldav](http://code.google.com/p/kcaldav/). They use libical for providing CalDAV support for KDE contacts.